# I have two javascript block in the page , one is adding dynamicllay which is , providing all images. should add above existing javascript on page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am using following code to add javascript dynamically

```
 HtmlGenericControl scriptTagLinks = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
 scriptTagLinks.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
 var scrip = "var aImgs=[" + appendString.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "]";
  scriptTagLinks.InnerHtml = scrip;
```

Javascript is adding to ascx page . But my problem I have two javascript block in the page , one is adding dynamicllay which is , providing all images. another one javascript as follows .

```
<script type="text/javascript>
     window.onload = function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < aImgs.length; i++) {
            var oImg = new Image();
            oImg.src = aImgs[i];
            aImages.push(oImg);

            oImg.onload = function () {
                textureWidth = oImg.width;
                textureHeight = oImg.height;
            }
        }} 
</script>
```

but dynamically created javascript is being added below the script . But should add above the script like this .

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var aImgs = [
        'DesktopModules/DNAiusCubeImages/Check/pic1.jpg',
        'DesktopModules/DNAiusCubeImages/Check/pic2.jpg',];
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript>
         window.onload = function () {
         for (var i = 0; i < aImgs.length; i++) {
                var oImg = new Image();
                oImg.src = aImgs[i];
                aImages.push(oImg);

                oImg.onload = function () {
                    textureWidth = oImg.width;
                    textureHeight = oImg.height;
                }
            }} 
    </script>How can i achieve this .
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing this.

```
 // Form the script that is to be registered at client side.
   String scriptString = "<script language=JavaScript> function DoClick() {";
   scriptString += "myForm.show.value='Welcome to Microsoft .NET'}<";
   scriptString += "/";
   scriptString += "script>";

       if(!this.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("clientScript"))
          this.RegisterClientScriptBlock("clientScript", scriptString);
```

Example in MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.71%29

The client-side script is emitted just after the opening tag of the Page object's  element. The script block is emitted as the object that renders the output is defined, so you must include both tags of the  element.

By identifying the script with a key, multiple server control instances can request the script block without it being emitted to the output stream twice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.
You can add a script without an event onLoad. Just a function that recieves your array of image paths.

And then using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...); from OnLoad event on server-side code, you can call your Javascript function and pass the parameters (Array) you need.